# Recursive issue on non-recursive script - Parallel Processing

Tags: python, recursion, multiprocessing, joblib

I'm having trouble with parallel processing on a news scraping script.

I have the following script that reads a google news rss page and processes each of the links returned. `news_list` is a BeautifulSoup element which contains information on the 10 most recent news on some subject.

```
def main(news_list):
    news_list = soup_page.findAll("item")

    feed = []

    for article in news_list[:10]:
        new = {}
        new['title'] = article.title.text
        new['source'] = article.source.text
        new['link'] = article.link.text
        new['date'] = datetime.strptime(article.pubDate.text, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z')
        new['keywords'] = keywords(article.link.text)

        feed.append(new)
```

The function `keywords` processes the news content and return salient keywords. This function takes about 1.5 seconds per news article, so the full script takes at least 15 seconds to run.

I want to reduce the duration of the script so i've been trying multiprocessing instead of the for loop, like this:

```
def process_article(article):
    new = {}
    new['title'] = article.title.text
    new['source'] = article.source.text
    new['link'] = article.link.text
    new['date'] = datetime.strptime(article.pubDate.text, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z')
    new['keywords'] = keywords(article.link.text)

    return new

from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import multiprocessing

num_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()     
feed = Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(delayed(process_news)(article) for article in news_list[:10])
```

However, im getting an error as if the function process_article was recursive:

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

What am i doing wrong? It still happens if I write the function as the following, so the `keywords` function is not the problem

```
def process_article(article):
    new = {}
    return new
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

---

This is the full traceback:

```
RecursionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-90-498afb9f1a25> in <module>
      1 num_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
      2 
----> 3 results = Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(delayed(process_news)(article) for article in list(news_list[:10]))

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in __call__(self, iterable)
    787                 # consumption.
    788                 self._iterating = False
--> 789             self.retrieve()
    790             # Make sure that we get a last message telling us we are done
    791             elapsed_time = time.time() - self._start_time

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py in retrieve(self)
    697             try:
    698                 if getattr(self._backend, 'supports_timeout', False):
--> 699                     self._output.extend(job.get(timeout=self.timeout))
    700                 else:
    701                     self._output.extend(job.get())

/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py in get(self, timeout)
    642             return self._value
    643         else:
--> 644             raise self._value
    645 
    646     def _set(self, i, obj):

/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py in _handle_tasks(taskqueue, put, outqueue, pool, cache)
    422                         break
    423                     try:
--> 424                         put(task)
    425                     except Exception as e:
    426                         job, idx = task[:2]

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/pool.py in send(obj)
    369             def send(obj):
    370                 buffer = BytesIO()
--> 371                 CustomizablePickler(buffer, self._reducers).dump(obj)
    372                 self._writer.send_bytes(buffer.getvalue())
    373             self._send = send

RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Comment: Look at the traceback and see what is repeating.

Comment: I'm not sure how to interpret it (added it to original post)